# Assigning Specific Input Bits to Separate Registers in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, simulation, hdl

I have a 128-bit input that I am trying to assign to four different 32-bit registers. I believe the issue is the way I have the 128-bit input coded in my test bench because my output is just a 128-bit string of zeros.

I could also have an error in the way I am defining these registers in my HDL code, but I'm not sure.

Here is my HDL code:

```
module RC6_encryption( in, clk, out );
input [0:127] in ;
input clk;
output reg [0:127] out;

reg [0:31] A;
reg [0:31] B;
reg [0:31] C;
reg [0:31] D;

//<statements>

assign A = in[0:31] ;
assign B = in[32:63] ;
assign C = in[64:95] ;
assign D = in[96:127] ;

endmodule
```

Here is my testbench code:

```
module RC6_tb();

parameter clk_period = 20;

reg [0:127] in;
reg clk;

wire [0:127] out;

//<statements>

initial 
begin 
    clk = 128'b0;
    in = 128'b0;
    
    #(clk_period);
    #(clk_period);
    #(clk_period);
    #(clk_period);
    #(clk_period);
    in = 128'hFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    //in = 128'b00001100000011010000111000001111000010000000100100001010000010110000010000000101000001100000011110000001000000011000000000000000;

$stop; 
end

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Clock Driver
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
always 
    #10 clk = ~clk;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Instantiate Unit Under Test:  multichannel_counter
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
RC6_encryption RC6_encryption_0 (
    // Inputs
    .in(in),
    .clk(clk),

    // Outputs
    .out(out)

);
endmodule
```

[image]

Comment: You are using continuous assignment for A, B, C, D. They must be declared as 'wire'(This should have appeared as compilation error).  If A,B,C,D are indeed reg, you wouldn't be using assign.
And why do you need clock and out? In the test-bench, after you set a non zero value to input, give some delay before stopping the simulation.

Comment: You have already gotten an answer, but for future questions like this you should include the exact error message produced by your compiler or synthesis tool.

Comment: Or if there's no compilation error you should explain what about the output is different from what you expected.

Comment: If you're asking why the `out` signal is always `X`, it's because you never assigned anything to `out`. Not in any continuous assignment and not in any procedural assignment.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for the advice and sorry if I wasn't being clear. I was confused as to why my input signal is showing up as all 0's in ModelSim when it was defined as all 1's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `assign` statements, which are continuous assignments. So signals `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` should be of type `wire`, not `reg`. This is of course assuming that you don't drive these signals elsewhere in your full code.

Also, after changing inputs to 1s, add appropriate delay. Because right now, you are stopping simulation immediately after changing the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried that but I am still getting an output of zero for all registers. I believe the issue is related to how I am defining my input. If you look at the screenshot my input signal is all 0's when I have defined it to be all 1's.

Comment: Cz you stopped the simulation right after changing the inputs. There is no delay or anything. Simulator works in time steps. So define timescale and add appropriate delays.